# How to escape html code with html allowed

Tags: html, escaping

i am a little confused how to use escape function on a variable having html code in it. i have tried this 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data 
but i could not figure it out.
 here is my code:

```
    $output = '<p>';
    $output .= '<label for="' . esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ) . '">Title:</label>';
    $output .= '<input type="text" class="widefat" id="' . esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'title' ) ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $title ) . '"';
    $output .= '</p>';   
    echo $output;
```

My question is how i can escape $output without losing html in it?
i am asking because i am submitting this code on themeforest. from where i have been rejected few times because of not escaping code. So now i think it is better to escape there variables. write?
thank you!

Comment: Escape HTML = Lose HTML!

Comment: Note that the `$output` variable is completely unnecessary here, all it does is introduce an opportunity for early escaping and a variable that's impossible to escape.

Comment: i am running to a similar problem in review, How did you pass the review in this case?

Answer (score 14):

You are looking for `wp_kses()`. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses/

There are more helper functions like `wp_kses_post()` and `wp_kses_data()`

Answer (score 1):

**1. Escaping**

- Escaping Attribute `<label for="<?php esc_attr( $tid ); ?>">`
- Escaping HTML   `<label ..><?php esc_html( 'Text' ); ?></label>`

---

**2. Translation and Escape**

**Note:**

- `textdomain` should be your own unique theme/plugin slug.
- The translated string should contain a static value. If you have a dynamic value then no need to make it translation ready.

1. Escape and translate Attribute: `<label for="<?php esc_attr( $tid ); ?>">`

No need to make it translation ready. If you have a static string with `$tid` then you need to make it transition ready eg.

**Invalid:**

```
<label for="<?php esc_attr__( $tid, 'textdomain' ) ); ?>">
<label for="<?php printf( esc_attr__( '%s', 'textdomain' ), $tid ); ?>">
```

**Valid:**

```
<label for="<?php printf( esc_attr__( '%s static text', 'textdomain' ), $tid ); ?>">
```

2. Escape and translate HTML: `<label ..><?php esc_html__( 'Text', 'textdomain' ); ?></label>`

Comment: This comment doesn't answer the question. Both esc_attr() and esc_html() remove any HTML in the string.

Answer (score 1):

try with this method. this is work for me. echo escape with html.

```
$output = '<p>';
$output .= '<label for="' . esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ) . '">Title:</label>';
$output .= '<input type="text" class="widefat" id="' . esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ) . '" name="' . esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'title' ) ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $title ) . '"';
$output .= '</p>';   

$allowed_html = array(
    'input' => array(
        'type'  => array(),
        'id'    => array(),
        'name'  => array(),
        'value' => array(),
     ),
);

echo wp_kses($output ,$allowed_html );
```

Comment: If you are using `checkbox` you need add like this

`$allowed_html = array(
   'input' => array(
    'type'  => array(),
    'id'    => array(),
    'name'  => array(),
    'value' => array(),
    'checked'  => array(),
    'onclick' => array() <== This is optional
   ),

  ); `

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks and works fine for me. The HTML in `value` is preserved.

My only recommendation would be to wrap all your text strings in `__()` or `_e()` so they can easily be translated. This is a nice selling point on marketplace sites like ThemeForest since not everyone wants to use English.

```
$output .= '<label for="' . esc_attr( $tid ) . '">' . __( 'Title:', 'your-text-domain' ) . '</label>';
```

Read more about [I18n on the WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers#Text_Domains).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it the "WordPress way", you would not store your HTML in a temporary variable, you would output directly.

```
?> 
<p>
    <label for="<?php esc_attr_e( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>"> <?php _e('Title:', 'tex-domain'); ?></label>
    <input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php esc_attr_e( $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) ); ?>" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $title ); ?>" />
</p>
<?php
```

P.S: You would also [internationalize](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers) your text strings.